# PHP script resetting at ~60 seconds and starting over again

Tags: php

I have an Opencart site that I'm trying to export products from using a module. The server is set up using nginx/php5-fpm/mariadb. When I run my export the timer gets to around ~60 seconds and then restarts over and over again.

I've checked several php settings such as:

max_execution_time  120

max_input_time  120

max_input_vars  25000

memory_limit    512M

Nothing shows up in the logs either. What could I be missing?

ANSWER:

My token session was being reloaded via java script to keep the admin session active. This was interfering with the connection of the php script being executed as a module through OC.

Comment: there could be a timer in the code itself

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the script is stopping but what I use to run a `php` script for long time is :

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(true);
//the rest of the code...
```

---

[set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

> Set the number of seconds a script is allowed to run. If this is
>   reached, the script returns a fatal error. The default limit is 30
>   seconds or, if it exists, the max_execution_time value defined in the
>   php.ini.

---

[ignore_user_abort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php)

> Sets whether a client disconnect should cause a script to be aborted.
>   When running PHP as a command line script, and the script's tty goes
>   away without the script being terminated then the script will die the
>   next time it tries to write anything, unless value is set to TRUE

---

**TIP**

You may want to enable **error reporting** to check if the script contains any errors, i.e.:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've tried all this and no change. I've messaged the module developer and if he comes up with anything I'll be sure to leave it here. I noticed a few other people have had similar issues with no answer.

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER:

My token session was being reloaded via java script to keep the admin session active. This was interfering with the connection of the php script being executed as a module through OC.